# How to stop tomcat after changing default shutdown port and shutdown word?

Tags: security, tomcat, java

I modified the `server.xml` and edited:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

To something else such as the following to get security by obscurity:

```
<Server port="8888" shutdown="myCustomShutdown">
```

However now when I run shutdown.sh I get the error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

which makes sense because I changed the port and shutdown command. However I can't find any reference in the .sh files, bin folder, etc. on how to adjust my `shutdown.sh` script to work with the new settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on Tomcat 8 and it works.
Did you first shutdown the tomcat and then changed the port and command ?

If not, restore the port and command settings, shutdown the server and then edit the shutdown settings before restarting it again.